# Godaddy domain name, DtDNS dynamicDNS, Django app, blank page

Tags: python, django, apache, raspberry-pi3

I have a weird problem at hand and I don't seem to understand the problem or find anyone who is having the same problem.

I have bought a domain name on godaddy, and I want to host my personal website on my raspberry pi.
I built my website using Django, and everything works well. I use Apache2 on my raspberry with mod_wsgi.
Now I connected my raspberry pi to my router and registered a name on DtDNS and connected my router to it so my dynamic IP is updated automatically.
When I access my website (from home or from my workplace - so I know my website is available from everywhere and not just my local network) it works as expected and I have full access to all the webpages I built.

Now comes the problem. I redirected (301) my domain name on godaddy to my name on DtDNS. When I comment the part deploying my django website in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf  , and I connect to my domain name on godaddy, I see the apache page "it works !", so I know the redirection works. BUT, when I deploy my django app, and connect to my domain name on godaddy, I have a blank page. (but I still see it when I connect to my name on dtdns !).

I have allowed my name both my name on dtdns and on godaddy in ALLOWED_HOSTS, in settings.py.

Did I do something wrong ? 
I came to this configuration (godaddy domain -> dtDNS -> django on raspberry) because initially I had a non django website hosted on godaddy, I wanted to convert it to django (I'm a python user) and I wanted to drop off the godaddy host, so I read a lot of tutorials and came to this.

Thanks a lot in advance !
P.S. : don't hesitate to ask me to include some info/conf etc...
EDIT:
Here is my apache conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        Alias /static /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/images/static/
        Alias /media/ /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/images/media/

        <Directory /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/images/static>
            Require all granted
            </Directory>

        <Directory /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/images/media>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/myapp>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
            WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/home/pi/workspace/website_perso python-home=/home/pi/workspace/website_perso/julienenv
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/workspace/website_perso/myapp/wsgi.py

    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and here is my django settings file :
    """
    Django settings for julienkaradayi project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '7(0v67_hclc-kyq^b!)3z6#)$3($6#2@68e7$)!m&+2*iokg-u'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP.IP.IP.IP','mydomain.slyip.com','mygodaddydomain.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_user_agents',
    'images',
]

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images/static')

# MEDIA

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + "/images/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

P.P.S. : I forgot to mention that when I disable the url masking on godaddy redirection, it works and I can access my website, but the dtdns url appears. I really want my domain name from godaddy to show. Is it possible to do that without breaking everything ?

Comment: without any code to look at, all I can suggest is to try to reverse the polarity...

Comment: I included my settings.py and my 000-default.conf (that I edited to work with my app). 
What do you mean by reversing the polarity ?

Comment: reverse the polarity: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReversePolarity

Comment: It looks like you're missing a ServerName declaration in your VirtualHost (which should match one of the items in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting), but other than that it looks ok.  For your pps you might want to read about reverse proxy.